# Different Color Shades of Material Design Color Palette

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I have been using different themes in my app and using the colors from the Material Design Color Palette ([here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette))

I see various shades of a particular color denoted by numbers ranging from 50 to 900.

My requirement is to generate lighter and darker shades of the primary color dynamically. I can easily do that. But I want to know the opacity corresponding to the particular shades.

Like the how much darker is the 700 shade from the 500 shade? If I know the various opacity values I can easily generate different colors dynamically.

**I need to know the opacity corresponding to the numbers assigned to the various shades?**

Comment: They colors in the material design specification all have 100% opacity, they are just darker/lighter shades of each other. If you want to know, you'll have to test out different opacity values of the dark colors yourself and see if you can match the others.

Answer (score 0):

**All of the colours in the material design colour palette have a 100% opacity level.** I don't see a way to be able to generate these dynamically; you will have to add all of the colours you need in your `color.xml` file and then reference them whenever you need to.